# Stop div moving when hits the edge of external dive with jquery annimate

Tags: css, jquery-animate, position

I have a div with an image and want the user to move it about inside a div but i dont want it to go outside the div.
As the div moves it will still go outside the parent area div and move over the rest of the page which i dont want

Here is my style used

```
<style>
#area{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: auto;
    clear: both;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
}
#one{
    width: 29px;
    height: 29px;
    background-image: url("images/fighter.png");
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
}

button{
    float: left;
    width: 50px;
}
.gameControls{
    margin: auto;
    width: 150px;
}
.gameUp{
    margin: 0 0 0 50px;
}
.clear{
    clear: both;
}
```

Here is my jQuery script used

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.gameUp').click(function(event){
            $("#one").animate({"top": "-=50px"}, "slow");
        });
        $('.gameLeft').click(function(event){
            $("#one").animate({"left": "-=50px"}, "slow");
        });
        $('.gameDown').click(function(event){
            $("#one").animate({"top": "+=50px"}, "slow");
        });
        $('.gameRight').click(function(event){
            $("#one").animate({"left": "+=50px"}, "slow");
        });
    });
</script>
```

And my body code

```
<div class="gameControls">
    <button class="gameUp">&uarr;</button>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <button class="gameLeft">&larr;</button>
    <button class="gameDown">&darr;</button>
    <button class="gameRight">&rarr;</button>   
</div>
<div id="area">
<div id="one"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that it can be done using only css, becouse `top`, `margin`, `padding` and etc can be assigned to negative value.

This my js solution:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D6s6K/2/)